# Boolean Filter on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to build a filter that corresponds to the **has_images** method on my Django admin, but I can't because it strictly says that **has_images** is not a field of the model. I tried setting it up as a property, but it also didn't work.

I thought about defining **has_images** as a field and really calculating it, based on the changes on the model, but I think that would be not optimal.

What would be a good solution here?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=255)

    def has_images(self):
        return self.images.all().count() > 0
    has_images.boolean = True

class ProductImage(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    file = models.ImageField("Product Image")
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImage
    fields = ('file',)
    extra = 1

class ProductAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'has_images',)
    inlines = (ProductImageInline,)
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share the contents of the admin.py file?

Or let me explain it as follows. Add a feature called `list_filter = ('images')`  into the ProductAdmin class you created in admin.py. If this feature doesn't work (I'm not sure as I haven't tried it), if you create an Admin Class for ProductImages directly, you can already view the pictures and the corresponding Product on that page.

----------- EDIT ----------------

This is how I solved the problem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=255)
    is_image = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.images.count():
            self.is_image = True
        else:
            self.is_image = False
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ProductImage(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    file = models.ImageField("Product Image")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductImage, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        self.product.save()
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class ProductImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImage
    fields = ('file',)
    extra = 1

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name',)
    list_filter = ('is_image',)
    inlines = (ProductImageInline,)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Here I added an is_image BooleanField field with False by default. Every time the save method of the Product model runs, it checks whether there is an image in the ProductImage to which the Product model is attached. If there is an image in it, is_image is set as True.

Comment: I edit it to include the admin.py up there

Comment: I considered doing that, but I didn't want to store the variables on the db. It works though, the only consideration I have to make is that it would be preferable to overwrite the ProductImage, right? Because the image would not be saved yet on that step of the way. I think the flow for saving is: PRODUCT and then PRODUCTIMAGE, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, first of all, the process takes place on the Product model and then on ProductImage. That's why we override the save method of the ProductImage model and call the Product model's save method again. I would like to add that, in the projects we have developed, I and the company I work for do not use the admin panel of django. In such a case, the filtering you want can be done easily only through the query, without keeping an extra field in the database.